# Component styles not re-rendering after page load in next.js website

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I am using a hook called useScrollPosition to animate certain things in my pages (opacity, height etc) dependent on the scroll position. The problem is that if the page is scrolled down and then you refresh then when the page loads Next.js renders it on the server and it doesn't update when it hits the page so the scroll position (and hence the animated components) are all wrong.

The hook is designed not to do anything on the server so the server renders with a default value, it should then update correctly when the component first hits the page, but it is not doing that for some reason.

I have set up a simple codesandbox to illustrate this but have included the important code below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/p5y6262qzm

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useScrollPosition = () => {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") return 500;

  // Store the state
  const [scrollPos, setScrollPos] = useState(window.pageYOffset);

  // On Scroll
  const onScroll = () => {
    setScrollPos(window.pageYOffset);
  };

  // Add and remove the window listener
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    };
  });

  return scrollPos;
};

export default useScrollPosition;
```

As you can see, when rendered on the server it sets an arbitrary value of 500 so that I can demonstrate the problem.

```
import useScrollPosition from "../hooks/useScrollPosition.js";

const boxStyles = {
  position: "fixed",
  width: "100%",
  top: 0,
  backgroundColor: "hotpink"
};

const Box = () => {
  const scrollPos = useScrollPosition();
  const headerHeight = scrollPos;
  return (
    <div style={{ height: headerHeight, ...boxStyles }}>
      Height: {headerHeight}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Box;
```

The pink box should render at height 500 on the server but once the page hits the browser and is rendered it should be set to a height equal to the scroll position, but it doesn't until you move the scroll bar.

What is even stranger is that I'm using the scroll value to update the height of the box AND to update a text label. You'll see by running the code sandbox that the label is correct at all times but the height of the box isn't.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: I can't edit the sandbox

Comment: Sorry @evgenifotia I'm new to Code Sandbox, is it possible to fork it? I'll see if I can change some options to let you edit it.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find any option to allow anonymous editing. I have put it into "frozen" mode which says if you try to edit it it should fork it.

Comment: me too I can't understand why it acts so worriedly. I made some change to get ride of the problem check this https://codesandbox.io/s/v36nzzj407

Comment: Interesting solution, you're basically tricking the component into updating by setting something in getInitialProps which changes in the browser version and passing it to the component to get it to update. I wonder if there's a way of doing this in some way that doesn't require it to be done in every page and passed to the component every time? I still wonder why this happens in the first place and why label updates but the style doesn't when the page hits the browser?

Comment: You can use `getInitialProps` in the `_app.js` file witch will work on all pages.